# RPCConvertValues() call error

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I'd like to call RPC programmatically, instead of using bitcoin-cli. when I call the function  `RPCConvertValues()`, it always raise error

`RPCConvertValues()` is defined here : https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/cab94cc07489f704c4b95171b23be0e8025df794/src/rpc/client.cpp#L221

test code are here : 
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/46fc4d1a24c88e797d6080336e3828e45e39c3fd/src/test/rpc_tests.cpp#L319
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/7967104aee055476107dc17265cefc4ae4e75378/src/bitcoin-cli.cpp#L293
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/eb292af309aa57f3d7998b01307dd4cb91702908/src/qt/rpcconsole.cpp#L302

My test code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <rpc/blockchain.cpp>
#include <rpc/request.h>
#include <rpc/client.h>
#include <rpc/util.h>
#include <univalue/include/univalue.h>
#include <interfaces/node.h>

namespace experimental {
    void wait(int seconds) { boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(seconds)); }

    void rpcgetblockhash() {
        wait(30);
        std::cout << "getblockhash RPC CALL!!" << std::endl;

        interfaces::Node* node;
        UniValue params = RPCConvertValues("getblockhash", {"0"}); // occurred error 
    }
}
```

Occurred error : 
[image]
I think that both are same between my function call form and function form of specified link above. I don't know why I'm getting error. can you give some guide?